# Repeat formula until next occurrence in another cell

Tags: excel

I'm having troubles creating an Excel formula to repeat the same copy down a column until I come to a new "person". The reason I'm doing this is to Index(Match) later to grab all this data. If I am totally off, and there's an easier way to grab this data than run a formula down 15k rows, I'm all ears. The main problem is that my categorical data (Person) is stacked on top of the data that I want to match it with (Work Positions).

The data looks like this:

```
Description | Status  
Bob | C  
Sales | 
Marketing |  
Management |  
John | C
Sales |  
Management |  
Tony | C
Management |
```

Ideally, I'd like the data to look like this after running the formula down ColA:

```
Person | Description | Status  
Bob | Bob | C  
Bob | Sales |   
Bob | Marketing |   
Bob | Management |   
John | John | C
John | Sales | 
John | Management | 
Tony | Tony | C
Tony | Management
```

I've tried writing an `If()` statement to target the "C" in ColC, as it is always there to discern a change in "Person". However, I can't figure out how to do this as of yet. Is there a way to write a formula that says keep pasting the same value until you hit the next "C", then change your paste value? Thanks for any and all help and please, don't hesitate to ask any clarifying questions!

Comment: "I've tried writing an `If()` statement"... Where is the code? Share what have you tried so far, what is working and what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(C:C="C",B:B,A1)
```

Put this in A2 and clear "Person" then drag down the list.

Comment: I don't think it should matter whether you clear "Person" or not because it doesn't refer to it is there is a "C" in C2.